# Android проблемы с Asynchronous Http Client

Tags: android, loopj

Добрый день!
Я использию библиотеку loopj для регистрации и логинизации и у меня возникли трудности с регистрацией. Две функции одинаковы по структуре. Примеры кода. Логигизация:

```
private void login(){

    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("email", "zzz@aa.com");
    params.put("password", "123456789");
    params.put("person", "0");

    Client.post("login", params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
            super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
            try {

                Log.d("Json_con", response.toString());

                String nameStr = response.getString("name");
                String snameStr = response.getString("surname");

                JSONObject id = response.getJSONObject("_id");
                String strId = id.getString("$oid");

                String str = nameStr + "    " + snameStr + "    " + strId;
                tv.setText(str);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Регистрация:

```
private void register(){

    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("email", "uuu@ii.com");
    params.put("name", "Lurk");
    params.put("surname", "More");
    params.put("password", "123456789");
    params.put("person", "0");

    Client.post("register", params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
            super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
            //Log.d("Json_reg", response.toString());

            try {
                JSONObject idJson = response.getJSONObject("_id");
                Log.d("Json_reg", response.toString());
                String strId = idJson.getString("$iod");
                Log.d("my_id", strId);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
            super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);
            Log.d("THROW", throwable.toString());
        }
    });

}
```

При регистрации выходит:

> W/JsonHttpRH﹕ onFailure(int, Header[], Throwable, JSONObject) was not overriden, but callback was received
>       org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Internal Server Error
>               at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.sendResponseMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:466)
>               at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest(AsyncHttpRequest.java:160)
>               at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries(AsyncHttpRequest.java:177)
>               at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run(AsyncHttpRequest.java:106)
>               at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

Почему с логином все в порядке с регистрацией не?
Старый код регистрации рабочи:

```
private void makeRegistration(){

        String nameString = nameEditText.getText().toString();
        String surnameString = nameEditText.getText().toString();
        String emailString = emailEditText.getText().toString();
        String passwordString = passwordEditText.getText().toString();


        ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<>();

        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", nameString));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("surname", surnameString));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", emailString));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", passwordString));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("person", userTypeInt + ""));

        Log.d("User_type", userTypeInt + "");

        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest("http://server/api/v1/register", "POST", param);

    Log.d("What_I_get_2", jsonObject.toString() + "\n");

    try {
        String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
        String surname = jsonObject.getString("surname");
        String id = jsonObject.getString("_id");

        Log.d("What_I_get", jsonObject.toString() + "\n" + id);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Где моя ошибка или ошибка в бблиотеке loopj.

Comment: Internal Server Error  - чет не то предаешь значит.

Answer (score 1):

Вместо "register"

```
 Client.post("register",
```

Нужно передать url регистрации. И надеюсь что `Client` это все же переменная и вы ее нечаянно с большой буквы назвали. Надеюсь помогло

**update**

И кстати Вы уверены, что у Вас с логином все впорядке?